# CAOpenGLLayer is not drawing

Tags: cocoa, opengl, core-animation

I'm drawing frames into CAOpenGLLayer, it works fine! But when i create second instance of it(in another thread and bind it to another CALayer), the first instance is stopping to draw(drawinCGLContext never been called), but setNeedsDisplay is calling regularly for each layer. If i create the third instance, then first and second aren't drawing, but third is good. I've tested that setNeedsDisplay 100% called and drawinCGLContext is not called for "old" layers and don't understand how it's happening.

Here's here is how my layer is creating:

```
MyCAOpenGLLayer* layer = [MyCAOpenGLLayer new];

layer.asynchronous = YES;
layer.autoresizingMask = kCALayerWidthSizable | kCALayerHeightSizable;
layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
[(CALayer*) wnd->getDrawingPrimitive() addSublayer:layer];
```

And here my drawinCGLContext function if it can help (but problem seemd not to be there): http://pastebin.com/5uBRDm4w

setNeedsDisplay is called when new frame is avaliable in special callback function.